# For loop with a non-integer increment in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, for-loop

Can a VB.NET `For` loop be constructed that mimics this C# code?

```
TimeSpan oneDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0);
for (DateTime d = startDate; d < endDate; d += oneDay) {
    // some code
}
```

Obviously you could do it *without* a `For` loop (i.e., with a `While`); I'm just curious if there's a certain syntax to construct a VB.NET `For` loop with a non-integer increment that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Isn't storing values in array an option?

Comment: @hgulyan: I'm sure there are a million ways to skin this cat from a functional perspective. I'm just curious if a syntax like this is possible in VB.NET, or if a `For` loop must always use an integer (or anyway, a *number*) as its counter.

Comment: Agree, it's an interesting question, but if there's a loop for other non-integer types:)

Comment: I'd write it `d = d.AddDays(1)`

Comment: @Joel: A long time ago I measured it and `AddDays` takes about twice as long as `+ [TimeSpan]`. Obviously it's a micro-optimization and not important at all; but I personally don't find either method more readable than the other so I tend to go with the faster one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, the VB For loop does not support using a DateTime.

Comment: It certainly seems like you're right; but do you have a reference?

Comment: Well the documentation says *Data Types. The data type of counter  is usually Integer but can be any type that supports the greater than or equal to (>=), less than or equal to (<=), addition (+), and subtraction (-) operators. It can even be a user-defined type provided it supports all these operators.*. `DateTime` only has static versions of those methods.

Comment: The link I copied that from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @ho: I think the issue with `DateTime` isn't that the versions are static (operator overloading is always static, I believe) but rather that `DateTime` does not define the `+` operator on another `DateTime` -- it's defined on a `TimeSpan`. That said, your comment definitely answers the question for good.